# When using React 18 + Jest I get SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, ts-jest

I have small component which uses OpenLayers 7.1 and I have this there:

```js
import Map from "ol/Map";
```

When trying to run tests using jest (and jest-ts & co) I get:

```
   /Users/jtiai/Code/react-openlayers/.yarn/cache/ol-npm-7.1.0-d92c823b1e-0935be63be.zip/node_modules/ol/Map.js:4
    import BaseObject from './Object.js';
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      1 | import React from "react";
      2 | import { Box } from "@mui/material";
    > 3 | import Map from "ol/Map";
        | ^
      4 |
```

What config I am missing?

Comment: What about adding this to the root of jest-config.js? 
```transformIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!(ol|@babel|jest-runtime))'],```